# IVP for Non-Separable Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I don't know how to go about this question. I would appreciate your help.
given information:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{y}{2\sqrt{xy}}+sinx}{\frac{x}{2\sqrt{xy}}+3y^2}    , y(\pi)=0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: this equation is exact.

Answer: 
$\sqrt{x y} - \cos x + y^3 =1$